# No-where dense sets in the reals

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

We have a theorem $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is n.w.d. $\longleftrightarrow \text{cl}(A)$ is n.w.d.
Where n.w.d. means "no-where dense" of course...

I was thinking to myself-- does there exist two n.w.d. distinct not closed sets whose closures are the same? I think this is possible with some weird discrete sets in  the reals... For example:
$$
A=\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}\cup \left\{2+\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}, \\B=\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\{0\}\cup \left\{2+\frac{1}{n+1}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
This is an example that answers my question in the affirmative, ... But this example is really unsatisfying...
So, my question is: what are the known limitations to this? Can distinct not closed no-where dense sets whose closures are the same be both uncountable? I suspect the answer is yes, with some careful attention to details. If two uncountable sets $A,B$ are disjoint but no where dense, not closed, how big can $\text{cl}(A)\cap \text{cl}(B)$ be? Size continuum?
As a variation of the above question, what if the sets $A$, $B$ are precisely in the above question except their intersection is finite? countable?i.e. (almost disjoint)

I realize that I asked a lot of questions in one post but that is because I suspect that there exists a relatively short answer that covers a lot of my questions. 
I'm not sure how to tag this question, feel free to re-tag as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily arranged.

Just take any two subsets of the Cantor set (or any non-discrete nowhere dense set) such that the closure of each is the Cantor set. For example, if we consider the set of interval endpoints from the construction, this is a countable dense subset of the Cantor set, and its complement is also dense in the Cantor set.

Both are subsets of the Cantor set, so they are nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$. They are even disjoint.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I was just about to write something down involving Cantor set. Ha.

Comment: Well, tough cookie. I type fast! :D

Comment: I somehow find these examples unsatisfying.. However, intuitively--these types of examples seem to be, (right now), as the only ones--so I guess there probably isn't a "satisfying" example anyway...

Comment: Guess what I'm looking for isn't there... I'm trying to think of some way something weird could happen--but alas too much is known about $\mathbb{R}$ at this point....

Comment: However!!!!! Great answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as to what you mean by that. Recall that the Cantor set is uncountable, so it has more subsets than you can imagine. Most are not Borel or anything, and you can take a fat Cantor set too, and have these sort of examples with the nowhere dense sets being relatively Bernstein sets, or Vitali sets, or many many other ways that you can think of weird dense subsets of a set sized continuum.

Comment: I think it would be prettier to take the set of left endpoints and the set of right endpoints as your two disjoint sets.

Comment: @bof: That would be prettier. I agree!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes!!! those are the *things* that I mean by that. I guess *weird* to me is just simply things I have less familiarity with. I've played with vitali sets, and cantor space a lot-- fat cantor sets yeah, those are nice. But bernstein sets! I need to play with those some more... I'm a newcomer to desc. set theory so *weird* means *unfamiliar* :)

Comment: @bof That makes sense. Yeah, I didn't think very deeply about the question...